# compare last string of the url, with the li's id name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to compare the last string of a url with the id of an `<li>` and if the same then do something. 
In my example below, I first use my code to compare it to a general ID and it works but I also need to target specific ids of the `<li>`s, need to mention that these `<li>`s start with a string "filter-", therefore I also need to remove "filter-" then get the last bit of the id and finally compare it to the last string of the url and if the same, do soemthing.. I tried this:

Example url:

```
url: http://www_example_com/category=.name
```

Example html:

```
<div class="leftNav">
   <ul id="name">
      <li id="filter-name">Lorem</li>
      <li id="filter-name2">Lorem</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Before the closing < /head>:

```
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
       var string = document.location.href.split('=.')[1];
       var stripString = $(".leftNav ul li").attr("id").replace("filter-", "");
       $(".leftNav ul").hide();
       $("#" + string).slideDown("slow");
       if(string == stripString) {
           $("#" + stripString).slideDown("slow");
       }
    });
```

Anyone? Thanks

Comment: What is "the last string of a url" exactly? Your URL examples looks a bit strange, is `=.name` really correct?

Comment: yes it is correct, i use "=." for something else, updated the example url tho. What i am trying to compare it to is whatever after the "=.", therefore in the example url should be "name". Thanks

Comment: You should go for another url formatting instead, because this one will cause you trouble. a hashtag would be a good way to go, e.g. http://example.com/#categoryname

Comment: i'm using this: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/hash-history.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you want this:

```
var token = document.location.href.split('=.')[1];
$(".leftNav ul").children().andSelf().hide();
$("#" + token).slideDown("slow");
$(".leftNav ul li[id$='"+token+"']").slideDown("slow");
```

or the last line could be changed to this:

```
$(".leftNav ul li#filter-"+token).slideDown("slow");
```

Comment: mm still only works "$("#" + token).slideDown("slow");" not that li bit

Comment: @rob.m I believe, it's because you are not hiding `li` elements.Will update my answer.

Comment: Guess what? I literally just realised I was exactly not hiding the li but its parent <ul>, I was coming to say "thanks" ..that why it wasn't working.. and bingo! You commented about it already :) - To conclude, I used this: $(".leftNav ul li#filter-"+token).parent().slideDown("slow");

Many thanks, I'll accept the answer

Comment: not need, in my case, for $(".leftNav ul").children().css('display','none'); - I have .leftNav ul display:none in the css anyway

Comment: @rob.m Anyway, I am hiding all the `ul` structure, no metter whether some of them are 'hidden' by css or not. :)